# CSS: repeat a "noise" on page stop at viewport

Tags: html, css

I have a div with this CSS:

```
.noise{background-image: url('../images/template/noise.png');
height:100%;
left:0;
 min-height:100%;
min-width:100%;
position:absolute;
top:0;
width:100%;
z-index:98!important;}
```

It has a noise PNG. The problem is that if viewport is longer that window, it doesn't repeat full screen.

See image:

[image]

I know that I could extend it via jquery, but, for sake to learn, is there a CSS-only tricks?

I hope I'm clear, thank you very much!

Comment: can you put it in a fiddle pls?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't put that bg image on the `body` tag?

Comment: You could try the `top:0; bottom:0;` trick ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `position:fixed` instead of `position:absolute`